# Как просмотреть журнал событий в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу посмотреть журнал событий, которые выполнял с БД (PostgreSQL), но что-то не могу найти команды для этого действия.

Хотел бы выводить: дату, время, пользователь которой зашел и какой запрос выполнил.
Кто может подсказать с этим.

Знаю такую команду `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` , но тут как-то не точно пишет

Answer (score 1):

> Хотел бы выводить: дату, время, пользователь которой зашел и какой запрос выполнил.

А с чего вы взяли, что эти гигабайты логов вообще куда-то сохраняются по-умолчанию? Их легко в день может быть больше чем сама база по объёму.

Сначала сами явным образом настраиваете [логирование](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html), потом ищете что вам понадобилось в логах. Вероятно вы захотите включить `log_connections`, `log_disconnections`, поменять `log_line_prefix` (либо задать `log_destination = csv` чтобы получить логи в `csv` формате) и поставить `log_statement = all`

---

[`view pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) показывает серверные процессы этого экземпляра postgresql (у вас может не быть прав на отображение всех полей этого `view`). Те, которые `backend_type = 'client backend'`, - процессы обслуживающие подключённых прямо сейчас клиентов и для них, в частности, поле `query` - последний выполненный запрос в этой сессии (или выполняемый сейчас в зависимости от `state`).